# Hypotenuse on a curved surface

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to triangulate the distance between two hoops of varying size in the construction of an elliptical crinoline. For the purposes of this question though, the shape of the object can be simplified to a section of a cone. I'm trying to find the hypotenuse of the triangle created by the curved base of the cone and the angled (but straight) edge of the cone. I've drawn a quick figure to help explain. I have the measurements for $A$ and $B$, and I'm looking for $C$. Because of the scale, I think either a curved $C$ (in blue) or a straight $C$ (in black) would work for my purposes, I'm not sure which would be easier to solve for.

Edit: I think I know how to solve it, but it's been so long since I was in geometry class, I can't for the life of me remember the formula I need. If I can solve for $D$ in this second picture, I think I can get the straight line $C$ from the first picture.
[image: 1]

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfEUm.jpg)

Comment: Is that a circular or elliptical cone? (You mentioned elliptical crinoline)

Comment: the base is circular. The style of crinoline is called elliptical because the virtical axis is tilted giving an optical illusion of an ellipse, however because of the scale I'm working with, I've simplified the geometry down to a standard circular cone. The materials I'm working with have enough give that my margine of error can allow for those simplifications.

Comment: If you don't need an exact result, you can simply use Pythagoras' theorem: $$C^2=A^2+B^2$$

Comment: For an exact result you need to know the slant height of the cone.

Comment: Because of the curve, the pythagorium theorem gives results that are just a hair too big, and because I'm using this formula for 38 small segments along the full height of the object, the end measurment is just a couple inches too long.

Comment: I should be able to calculate the slant height. I have the XY coordinates for the two points at either end of length B. Given the slant, what would the formula be?

Comment: @TishTosh I've been working on an answer but am having to guess at a couple of points so figured it was easier to ask you here. We need a bit more information to know the exact cone we're dealing with. Am I right that the easiest thing for you to measure/plan will be the radii of the two hoops and the distance between them? (It may help you to know that conceptually the way to find the shortest distance along the surface of a cone is to "unroll" it into a 2D net, then calculate the straight line distance on that net. This may also be the easiest way to do it in practice!)

Comment: In your second picture, $$D = 2r\sin \frac{A}{2r}$$

Comment: Also note that if you cut the cone by a line from apex to base, you can unroll it and lay it flat in a plane. That can make distance calculations such as these easier. The unrolling does not change any distances within the cone surface. $A$ will still be a section of a circle, but $B$ and $C$ will be straight lines.